# Accessing both inputs name and value from controller in Angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the following inputs and need both their 'name' and 'value' :

```
<script>
$scope.userAttributes = response.userAttributes.split(','); //$scope
/* OR */   
self.userAttributes = response.userAttributes.split(','); //controllerAs
</script>

<div class="item item-input" ng-repeat="userAttribute in userAttributes"> <!-- $scope -->
     <input type="text" name="{{userAttribute }}" dynamic-model="(userAttribute | alphanumeric | spaceToUnderscore | lowercase)">
</div>
<!-- OR -->
<div class="item item-input" ng-repeat="userAttribute in controllerAs.userAttributes"> <!-- controllerAs -->
     <input type="text" name="{{userAttribute}}" dynamic-model="'controllerAs.' + (userAttribute | alphanumeric | spaceToUnderscore | lowercase)">
</div>

<!-- Output example: -->

<input type="text" ng-model="your_age" name="Your Age"/> <!-- $scope -->
<!-- OR -->
<input type="text" ng-model="controllerAs.your_age" name="Your Age"/> <!-- controllerAs -->
```

nb: dynamic-model directive - allows you to apply filters to a value to generate the model name - eg, remove spaces etc.

With either of the previous **Output examples** methods how can I access both the name attribute "Your Age" and the user inputted value (eg: 23) from the controller, eg, on button click.

This is just an example and the ng repeat will have a varying number of inputs with variable names etc depending on many factors.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I see it, you have two options given your specific scenario:

1. Create a custom directive and from there you would be able to have access to all attributes through scope declarations on the directive.
2. Add the value of the name attribute to your model (i.e. userAttribute.value and userAttribute.name)

Example of 2 above.

Javascript:

```
var userAttributes = response.userAttributes.split(','); //$scope
$scope.userAttributes = [];
for(var attr in userAttributes){
    if(attr == "your_age"){
        $scope.userAttributes.push({value: attr, name: "Your Age"});
    }
    //...etc
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="item item-input" ng-repeat="userAttribute in userAttributes">
   <input type="text" name="{{userAttribute.attr}}" ng-model="userAttribute.value" />  //not sure on dynamic-model usage
</div>
```

Comment: btw, I have added some example JS, to demonstrate basically how I get the array for the ng-repeat

Comment: Added.  Does that help?  P.S. - This solution is overkill to me.  Short answer is that at some point, if you want to track the label and the model, you are going to have to do something like this or else you are doing using directives to reach back and crawl the DOM with angular.element

Comment: thanks @Chris Story, I had done something "similar", not sure how it works (especially the model/value part) but it does seem to work:
`var userAttributes  = response.userAttributes.settings.split(',');

                    self.userAttributes = [];

                    angular.forEach(userAttributes, function(value, key) {

                        self.userAttributes[ key ] = {name: value, value: ""};
                    });
<input type="text"  name="{{userAttribute.name}}" ng-model="userAttribute.value">`

Comment: In your case, your array was full of strings (hence {{userattribute}}).  I simply turned each array item into an object with the two properties you desired.

Comment: Thanks, but I mean, the method I did (in my comment above), I am not sure how it works - but it seems to be working.